# Prevent loss of data in recursive function

Tags: python-3.x, database, function, recursion, recurrence

I have a recursive function to which i pass certain args. The function is as below:

```
def insert_category(a, b, c, d, content_to_write):
    response_content = []
    
    if content_to_write:
        response_content.extend(content_to_write)
    
    for x in b:
        write_back_content = {}
        write_back_content = {"category_path": "a", "name": "b" ,"status" : "Successful" ,"err_desc" : "-" }
        form_category = {"pid": "0", "name": "Library" }
        category_exists = db.collection.find_one({"_id":a})
        if some_cond:
                write_back_content["status"] = "Failed"
                write_back_content["err_desc"] = "Duplicate Category"
                response_content.append(write_back_content)
                continue
        elif some_other_cond:
            write_back_content["status"] = "Failed"
            write_back_content["err_desc"] = "Invalid pid i.e category path"
            response_content.append(write_back_content)
            continue
        
        insert_status = db.collections.insert(form_category)
        if not insert_status:
            write_back_content["status"] = "Failed"
            write_back_content["err_desc"] = "Unable to create category"
            response_content.append(write_back_content)
            continue
        else:    
            c[map_some_id] = insert_status
            response_content.append(write_back_content)
        insert_category(a, b, c, d ,content_to_write=response_content)

    logger.info("RESPONSE CONTENT {}".format(response_content))
    return response_content
```

The current problem I am facing here is that the log line "RESPONSE CONTENT" somehow loses the last attached info, ex: if there are 4 insertions in response_content, when i call this function, the return response has only 3 insertions. The last one goes missing. Also, weirdly, the log prints 4 times instead of just once since it is outside the for loop.Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Could you please try to reproduce the problem with a much shorter code?

Comment: @Stef I have tried to simplify it. My main concern stands with holding that response_content data.

Comment: There's no need to define `write_back_content` and then immediately redefine it on the next line. That's pointlessly confusing.

Comment: @MarkSaving Well i had added that to avoid duplicating any keys since we are inside a for loop. But since there are just 4 keys getting assigned new values on every iteration, will remove that part now.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after quite a long time of debugging, i realised the mistake was quite silly. The function returns some data. So i was not storing the return content. So the solution that worked was **response_content = insert_category(args)**.